# How positioning FB-like popup-window on website

Tags: facebook

I tried to position the **popup-window** of Facebook -**Like**- Button.
so: the popup-window ... not the button.

I read several posts here.
It seems there is no real solution.
I'm looking for something for a "normal" website (NO Wordpress, Drupal etc.....)

Comment: this question is not clear enough, please try to explain your issue, put references for correct interpretation, like screenshots, link to website... also: what is FB-like popup-window? screenshot? link?

Answer (score 0):

I assume  you are talking about that popup where a user can enter a comment? You can´t move that one, it will be always at the same spot relative to the Like Button.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about that popup.

Comment: yeah, not possible to reposition that one, i am afraid. just make sure not to place it at the bottom of your page ;)